# Keycloak Implement Reset password flow same as forgot password flow

Tags: keycloak, forgot-password

I am facing an issue with Keycloak:

- When user clicks on Forget password button, he is asked to enter basic details. Once details are entered, the user receives a mail with link to change his password. User Changes his password, and is redirected to Login page of the application.
- Users account gets locked. Admin uses application to unlock the account. User gets email, clicks on link, and generates new password. User now sees a message : Your account is successfully updated.

What I want to do is that the second flow should work in same  way as the first one. i.e when user has given new password, he'd be redirected to login page.

Can someone guide me about how to proceed with this?

Difference I've noticed in two flows is the URL that I receive  in both of them is different.

First flow, I get this in mail: http://[keycloak-host]/auth/realms/[realm]/login-actions/reset-credentials?code=[code]

Second flow, I get this URL: http://[keycloak-host]/auth/realms/[realm]/login-actions/execute-actions?key=[key]

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. What is more, email templates for both aforementioned actions are different which makes things confusing for different. Did you manage to overcome the issue?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Any solution yet ?

Comment: As an ugly workaround, I suggest using inline script around here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66861665/keycloak-implement-reset-password-as-admin-flow-same-as-forgot-password/67104425#67104425