# Keycloak : implement "reset password" (as admin) flow same as "forgot password" (as user)

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I would like to implement this authentication flow in Keycloak:

1. A user creates an account by typing only his email
2. The user is logged in and can access my service
   2'. At the same time, an email is sent to him, allowing him to "finalize" his account
3. The user leaves his session -> to reuse my service, he must click in the received email
4. By clicking in the received email, the user defines his first password
5. The user is then logged in automatically (without going through a login page).

The objective of this flow is to be the simplest, to hook users who are not used to webapps.

The implementation I would do:

- Create an account without password request: I customize the Keycloak `Registration` flow by disabling the `Password Validation` and `Profile Validation` rules
- Programmatically, in my webapp, at the first connection of a user, via the REST Admin API, I trigger the email action `UPDATE_PASSWORD`

I get something that works, but:

A. The link received by email redirects to an intermediary page confirming the execution of actions ("Perform the following action (s)") - (similar to [Keycloak Implement Reset password flow same as forgot password flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021283/))

B. The user is then redirected to a login page, and not directly connected to the application.

When, as a normal user, I trigger a reset password request (through 'forget password' feature), the process is the one I want: by clicking on the email link, I go directly to the page allowing me to enter and confirm a new password, then I'm authenticated.

My question: **Do you see a way to implement this 'simplified' flow?**

My keycloak version : 11.0.2

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I could remove the "info.ftl" page display, customizing the "ExecuteActionsActionTokenHandler", as explained here :

[action-token-spi](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_development/topics/action-token-spi.adoc)

You have to create a file :

> src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.keycloak.authentication.actiontoken.ActionTokenHandlerFactory

containing the name of the class you want to use instead :

> com.example.ExecuteActionTokenHandlerFactory

Then you create that class com.example.ExecuteActionTokenHandlerFactory with the following code :

```java
public class ExecuteActionTokenHandlerFactory extends ExecuteActionsActionTokenHandler {


    @Override
    public Response handleToken(ExecuteActionsActionToken token, ActionTokenContext<ExecuteActionsActionToken> tokenContext) {
        AuthenticationSessionModel authSession = tokenContext.getAuthenticationSession();
        String redirectUri = RedirectUtils.verifyRedirectUri(tokenContext.getUriInfo(), token.getRedirectUri(),
                tokenContext.getRealm(), authSession.getClient());

        if (redirectUri != null) {
            authSession.setAuthNote(AuthenticationManager.SET_REDIRECT_URI_AFTER_REQUIRED_ACTIONS, "true");

            authSession.setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
            authSession.setClientNote(OIDCLoginProtocol.REDIRECT_URI_PARAM, redirectUri);
        }

        token.getRequiredActions().stream().forEach(authSession::addRequiredAction);

        UserModel user = tokenContext.getAuthenticationSession().getAuthenticatedUser();
        // verify user email as we know it is valid as this entry point would never have gotten here.
        user.setEmailVerified(true);

        String nextAction = AuthenticationManager.nextRequiredAction(tokenContext.getSession(), authSession, tokenContext.getClientConnection(), tokenContext.getRequest(), tokenContext.getUriInfo(), tokenContext.getEvent());
        return AuthenticationManager.redirectToRequiredActions(tokenContext.getSession(), tokenContext.getRealm(), authSession, tokenContext.getUriInfo(), nextAction);
    }

}
```

Actually it is the same implementation as the upper class, except we removed the following part :

```java
        if (tokenContext.isAuthenticationSessionFresh()) {
           ...
        }
```

which means that if the user did not have a session, which happens when the user is reseting his password, he is redirected to that "info.ftl" page.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for problem A, I customize `info.ftl` template page. I add an ugly inline script to `click` on the link, redirecting automatically to the update password page.

```html
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
(...)
            <#elseif actionUri?has_content>
              <p><a id="yolo" href="${actionUri}">${kcSanitize(msg("proceedWithAction"))?no_esc}</a></p>
              <script>document.getElementById('yolo').click()</script>
(...)
```

It'll do the job until I found a cleaner solution.

At the moment, B problem remains.

Comment: Hi, did you find any cleaner solution ? We are having the same problem!

Comment: Nope, good luck - and we've finally removed this workflow.